# If $M_A(x)=x^3-x$ So $M_{A^2}(x)=x^2-x$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

If $M_A(x)=x^3-x$ So $M_{A^2}(x)=x^2-x$ Where $M$ is the minimal polynomial

$x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x(x-i)(x+i)$ so $A$ is diagonalizable

$A=P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -i \\
\end{pmatrix}P$

$A^2=P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -i \\
\end{pmatrix}^2P=P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}^2P$

So $P_{A^2}(x)=x(x-1)^2$ but $A^2(A^2-1)=0$ so $M_{A^2}(x)=x(x-1)=x^2-x$

Is there another way to conclude it?

Comment: If $A^3-A=0$, pre (or post) multiply by $A$ ... so $A^2$ satisfies ...

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit $A^5-A^3=0\iff A^3(A^2-I)$

Comment: $A^4-A^2=0$ so $B=A^2$ satisfies $B^2-B=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $M_A(x) = x(x-1)(x+1)$ we conclude that $A$ is diagonalizable and $\sigma(A) = \{0, -1, 1\}$.

Hence $A^2$ is also diagonalizable and $\sigma(A)^2 = \sigma(A)^2 = \{0,1\}$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial $M_{A^2}$ has only linear factors and has zeroes $0, 1$.

The only option is $M_{A^2}(x) = x(x-1)$.

Comment: $ \sigma(A^2)=\sigma(A)^2?$

Comment: @newhere $\sigma(A^2) = \{\lambda^2 : \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$. The latter set is commonly denoted as $\sigma(A)^2$.

Comment: So we just take the power of the eigenvalues?

Comment: @newhere Yes, for any polynomial $p$ we have $\sigma(p(A)) = p(\sigma(A)) = \{p(\lambda) : \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

First you can plug in $A^2$ to see whether it satisfies the polynomial. Indeed:

$$(A^2)^2 - A^2 = A^4 - A^2 = A A^3 - A^2 = AA - A^2=0$$

Now check that $A^2$ doesn't satisfy the linear factors $x$ and $x-1$.

Comment: How did we get yo $AA - A^2=0$?

Comment: $AA = A^2$, right?